# angularjs access link function of directive from external controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

i have two `ng-include` in a template, but similar:

```html
<ng-include ng-controller="ctrTable" src="modal.html"></ng-include>

<ng-include ng-controller="ctrButton" src="modal2.html"></ng-include>
```

i need refresh the table table that is in the controller `ctrTable` but the button is in the controller and call a function of service`tableService` in the controller `ctrButton` and the table is a directive

**ctrTable.js**

```js
$scope.jqconfig = {
    url:Metronic.getAJAXURL() + "/ajax/getNames",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:[
              'id',
              'Name'
              ],
    width: null,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    colModel:[
      {name:'name',index:'name',autowidth: true,shrinkToFit: true},{name:'id',index:'id',autowidth: true,shrinkToFit: true}
    ],
    sortname: 'id',
};
```

**ctrButton.js**

```html
$scope.refresht = function(){ $tableService.refresh();}
```

**modal.html**

```
<ng-jqgrid config="jqconfig" addnew="true" modeldata="patientdata" gridid="patientgrid" pagerid="patientpager" api="gridapi"></ng-jqgrid>
```

**modal2.html**

```
<input type="button" ng-click="refresht()" />
```

**directive.js**

```
Handelbay.directive('ngJqgrid',[ '$window', function ($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        config: '=',
        api: '=?',
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var table, div;
        scope.$watch('config', function (value) {
            table.jqGrid(value);
            scope.api = {
                refresh: function () {
                    table
                        .jqGrid('clearGridData')
                        .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: scope.modeldata })
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            };
        });
    }
}; }]);
```

**TableService.js**

```
Handelbay.factory("$tableService", ['$rootScope','$http',function($rootScope,$http) {

return { refresh: function(){ /* refresh ??? */ } } }]);
```

Comment: are those modals or partials? you could include the code of one into the other (ie modal.html having modal2's ng-include inside) and acess it via DOM. To access it via JS you should use directive/component bindings (those "@","=","&" etc you see in directives)